# IPv6 - App rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Apple rejected my app and sent this message:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 11.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Is it an IPv6 network support issue?

Comment: Did you have a url with IP adress in your app? IP adresses like 192.168.1.1 cannot converted automatically to IPv6...

Comment: It may be nothing to do with IPv6 (or it may) They are just letting you know the environment they tested in.  You need to look at any other information they have provided to see what happened.  You should definitely test a TestFlight build on an IPv6 network

Answer (score 1):

Apple will reject if your app is not supporting IPv6. Are you using NSURLConnection in your app? If so migrate immediately to NSURLSession. Apple has clearly explained about this in here: https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

Comment: I have already use NSURLSession in my app. But still apple reject application.

Comment: Did you ask them the reason using the resolution center via iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes i have asked but no response from support team.                                                           Is this issue because of the api which we have implementing in our app, is required to configure over IPv6 network or not?

Comment: Give them some time they will respond :)